# How to draw a rectangle with a border pixel over a camera/viewport?

Tags: camera, game-maker, viewport

**With this code I intended to visually delimit the complete view of the circuit and the two controlled cars:**

```
draw_rectangle(0,0,1279,719,true);
draw_rectangle(0,720,639,1079,true);
draw_rectangle(640,720,1279,1079,true);
```

**It turns out that only the complete view of the circuit that is drawn directly in the room is correctly delimited (observe the black line of a thick pixel):**

[image]

**Where there should be the rectangle strokes (red line, not necessarily at this thickness):**

[image]

**This happens because of this camera/viewport:**

[image]

I believe the rectangle is being drawn under the camera/viewport.

What do I need to do to make this rectangle draw over the camera/viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just draw everything you want to overlay the camera image the way you would draw a **HUD/UI**. Using the **draw GUI event**.

**Result:**

[image]